# Regular Expression Matching Currency or Percent

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I need to match the following values and my current `Regular Expression` can't seem to get `%` values to be matched or numbers without `-` and `$`

Values I need a matched:

> $123.45 - Match
>
> -$123.45 - Match
>
> 123.45 - Needs Matched
>
> -123.45 - Match
>
> .99 - Needs Matched
>
> -.99 - Match
>
> 7% - Needs Matched
>
> -7% - Needs Matched
>
> 500 - Needs Matched

Regular Expression:

```
^[-$][$]?\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/^-?\$?[0-9]*\.?([0-9]{2})?%?$/
```

Comment: This also matches `-$.%`. This expression will probably need to get a lot longer with some ORs. Half the fun is matching what you want; the other half is _not_ matching what you _don't_ want.

Comment: /^-?\$?\d*\.?(\d{2})?%?$/ ( tiny bit shorter )

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = " 
$123.45 - Match
-$123.45 - Match
123.45 - Needs Matched
-123.45 - Match
.99 - Needs Matched
-.99 - Match
7% - Needs Matched
-7% - Needs Matched
500 - Needs Matched
";

preg_match_all('#-?[$]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}+[%]?#i',$str, $res);
print_r($res);
```

This casts the web a little to wide though as it finds -$123.12% to be a number

Answer (score 0):

```
/^-?\$?[0-9]*(\.?[0-9]{1,2})?%?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted on akellehe's answer to match a range of currency symbols:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^-?[^0-9]?[0-9]*[0-9\u002e]+%?$");
```

and to capture the output for more analysis:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(-?)([^0-9]?)([0-9]*[0-9\u002e]+)(%?)$");
// $1 captures the negative sign,
// $2 captures the currency symbol
// $3 captures the number
// $4 captures the percent sign
```